# FAT COLUMNS and performance MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to have two tables -  one for performance, and the other one for data, like so:

```
table_a:
ID          USER_ID          CONTENT_REF
0           15               34
1           163              35
2           3                36

table b:
ID          CONTENT
34          I think what you wanted to say was....
35          Sure, and why shouldn't we all keep on.....
36          Yeah... Right...
```

As you see, table_b serves for the more heavy data, like long posts. 
my question is code-wise.
What is the best approach to insert into these tables? 
Does it have to use last_insert_id()? or is there a better, more smooth method I am missing out here?

```
INSERT INTO table_b ..  VALUES (..)
INSERT INTO table_a .. VALUES ( .. , last_insert_id())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ensures that all queries run successfully or neither run if one were to fail.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT table_b (CONTENT)
  VALUES('string');
INSERT INTO table_a(USER_ID, CONTENT_REF) 
  VALUES( 163, LAST_INSERT_ID());
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the question answered itself, but cheers for the help ;)